# How to use a JPA query with parameterized Order By clause

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use JPA to a PostgreSQL DB with my repository

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<...> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY column1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<...> find1();

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<...> find2(String param);
}
```

`find1()` works fine: all rows are ordered by `column1`. But `find2("column1")` does not work.

How can I do it? I have to use native queries in any case, therefore I cannot resort to `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort`.

Comment: Have you tried using named parameters? [https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters)

Comment: @VitorSantos: Does not work, either.

Comment: You cannot do it with parameters like this. Your options are to either create all the queries by which you will allow sorting in both directions and select based on that, or to use the CriteriaBuilder. Postgresql determines the sorting algorithm during parse time, so you cannot even use integer parameters to select it, even though you can use integers to choose the columns in raw queries.

Comment: I solved it by using `entityManager.createQuery(selfMadeHqlQuery)`.